# Javascript how to know the current user? Session variable dont work? Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: require is not defined

Tags: javascript, django

please help I got stuck!

SO this is my js code

```
 document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
document.querySelector('#inbox-view').innerHTML = `<p class="header" >Messages</p> `;
fetch('/inbox')
.then(response => response.json())
.then(messages => {
 messages.forEach(message => {
let msection = document.createElement("div"); //create a clickable area
let content = `<a href="#" class="posta"><img src="${message.senderimage}" class="rounded-circle">
                    <h4> ${message.sendername}</h4> 
                    <p style="display:inline;"> @${message.sender}</p>  <p class="posta" id="myMessage"> ${message.content}</p> </a>                
                 <br> <br>
                 <hr>`;

msection.innerHTML = content; //set its content
msection.setAttribute('class','msec'); //set its style
msection.href ="#"; // make it clickable  
var session = require('express-session')
if(`${message.sender}` != session){
  document.querySelector('#inbox-view').append(msection);
}
```

**What I want is**

I have this dynamic content in a Django Project. I want to display only the messages didn't send by the current user( basically display an inbox, not reply messages)

In this section of my code

```
 var session = require('express-session')
if(`${message.sender}` != session){
  document.querySelector('#inbox-view').append(msection);
}
```

I want to check if the sender is current user if so I don't want to display that message.

I already install thee package

```
        npm install express-session
```

but still gives me this error:

```
         Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: require is not defined
at inbox:130
```

(Without this session thing code works just fine)

So what is the way of knowing the logged-in user? Is there any other way? Thank you

Comment: first `require` is not available client-side unless you have some sort of a build process, second, `express-session` is meant for an `Express` application running in `Node.js` (server-side). What you should do, instead, is to create an endpoint inside `Django` that will return the appropriate messages for the logged in user. You **should not** be doing this type of logic on client-side.

Comment: yeah I know it is written with Django. DO you know any other way I can detect the current user please? in Django it is as easy as saying request.user